# Not recursive (single node level) getElementsByTagName in Python xml.dom

Tags: python, xml, dom

Is there any way to use `getElementsByTagName` only at a single node level and not recursively?

E.g. consider parsing a `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>2.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.parent.somemodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>some_module</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Some Module</name>
    ...
```

If I want to get `groupId` at the top level (specifically `project->groupId`, not `project->parent->groupId`), I use:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse('pom.xml')
groupId = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("groupId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

But unfortunately, that finds the first physical occurrence of `groupId` in the file regardless of the hierarchy level, which is `project->parent->groupId`.  I actually want to do a unrecursive find ONLY at a specific node level, not within its children.  Is there a way to do it in [`xml.dom`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Document.getElementsByTagName)?

**UPDATE:**  I switched to [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) but still having the same problem with implicit recursive traversing: [Finding a nonrecursive DOM subnode in Python using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147686/finding-a-nonrecursive-dom-subnode-in-python-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over `getElementsByTagName()` results and take the first element that is in on the root level:

```
group_id_element =  next(element for element in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("groupId")
                         if element.parentNode == xmldoc.documentElement)

print group_id_element.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

Note that it would be easier, shorter and faster to do the same with [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), which is also a part of standard library.

Hope that helps.

Comment: so are you saying `ElementTree` is more granular and sophisticated?

Comment: @amphibient well, this is my opinion, of course. When I need to parse an xml file, I prefer to use `ElementTree`, `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: can you also please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146417/simple-dom-traversing-in-python-using-xml-etree-elementtree ?  Thanks

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147686/finding-a-nonrecursive-dom-subnode-in-python-using-beautifulsoup