# Finding a nonrecursive DOM subnode in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, dom, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

Is there any way to find a nonrecursive DOM subnode in Python using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

E.g. consider parsing a `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>2.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.parent.somemodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>some_module</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Some Module</name>
    ...
```

If I want to get `groupId` at the top level (specifically `project->groupId`, not `project->parent->groupId`), I use:

```
with open(pom) as pomHandle:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pomHandle)

groupId = soup.groupid.text
```

But unfortunately, that finds the first physical occurrence of `groupId` in the file regardless of the hierarchy level, which is `project->parent->groupId`.  I actually want to do a unrecursive find ONLY at a specific node level, not within its children.  Is there a way to do it in `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: Why are you using BeautifulSoup (an HTML parser) to parse well-formed XML?  Python has a perfectly good XML parser.

Comment: this is why:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146417/simple-dom-traversing-in-python-using-xml-etree-elementtree/21146487?noredirect=1#comment31827467_21146487

Comment: because i don't wanna have to deal with the namespace BS, which is apparently not ignorable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can search inside "project" node with `recursive=False`:

```
groupId = soup.project.find('groupid', recursive=False).text
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: you are my person of the day, @alecxe